# Count number of times current value exists

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, count

input:

```
<PackageInfo>
    <outerinfo>
        <myCompareInfo>12345</myCompareInfo>
    </outerInfo>
    <outerinfo>
        <myCompareInfo>67890</myCompareInfo>
        <containedInfo>12345</containedInfo>
    </outerInfo>
    <outerinfo>
        <myCompareInfo>55667</myCompareInfo>
        <containedInfo>12345-C</containedInfo>
    </outerInfo>
</PackageInfo>
```

output:

```
<OutputInfo>
    <Package>
        <PnNum>12345</PnNum>
        <Status>split</Status>
    </Package>
    <Package>
        <PnNum>67890</PnNum>
        <Status>avail</Status>
    </Package>
    <Package>
        <PnNum>55667</PnNum>
        <Status>avail</Status>
    </Package>          
</OutputInfo>
```

I need to do a count but I can't figure out the correct syntax. If the current myCompareInfo exists as a containedInfo value then the status should be split otherwise the status is avail. I created variables for current and count and if count > 0 I set the status but 1, that seems like more steps than is needed and more importantly, 2, it's not working.

```
<xsl:variable name="currentVal" select="./myCompareInfo/text()" />
<xsl:variable name="splitCount" select="/count(OutputInfo[contains(@myCompareInfo,$currentSSCC)])" />
```

What am I doing wrong with the count?

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

     <xsl:key name="kContained" match="myCompareInfo"
      use="boolean(/*/*/containedInfo[contains(., current())])"/>

     <xsl:template match="/*">
      <OutputInfo><xsl:apply-templates/></OutputInfo>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="outerInfo">
      <Package><xsl:apply-templates/></Package>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="myCompareInfo">
      <PnNum><xsl:apply-templates/></PnNum>
      <Status>available</Status>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match=
     "myCompareInfo
              [count(.|key('kContained', 'true'))
              =
               count(key('kContained', 'true'))
              ]">
      <PnNum><xsl:apply-templates/></PnNum>
      <Status>split</Status>
     </xsl:template>
     <xsl:template match="containedInfo"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the (corrected to be well-formed) provided XML document:**

```
<PackageInfo>
    <outerInfo>
        <myCompareInfo>12345</myCompareInfo>
    </outerInfo>
    <outerInfo>
        <myCompareInfo>67890</myCompareInfo>
        <containedInfo>12345</containedInfo>
    </outerInfo>
    <outerInfo>
        <myCompareInfo>55667</myCompareInfo>
        <containedInfo>12345-C</containedInfo>
    </outerInfo>
</PackageInfo>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<OutputInfo>
   <Package>
      <PnNum>12345</PnNum>
      <Status>split</Status>
   </Package>
   <Package>
      <PnNum>67890</PnNum>
      <Status>available</Status>
   </Package>
   <Package>
      <PnNum>55667</PnNum>
      <Status>available</Status>
   </Package>
</OutputInfo>
```

---

**II. XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kContained" match="myCompareInfo"
  use="boolean(/*/*/containedInfo[contains(., current())])"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <OutputInfo><xsl:apply-templates/></OutputInfo>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="myCompareInfo">
  <PnNum><xsl:apply-templates/></PnNum>
  <Status>available</Status>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "myCompareInfo[. intersect key('kContained', true())]">
  <PnNum><xsl:apply-templates/></PnNum>
  <Status>split</Status>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="outerInfo">
  <Package><xsl:apply-templates/></Package>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="containedInfo"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```